# Llamar una función javascript desde otra usando como parámetro un string

Tags: javascript

Quisiera invocar una función en javascript donde pueda enviar como parámetro otra función y que se pueda ejecutar, por ejemplo.

```
function uno ('function dos('parametro_1','parametro_2')')
//-------
function uno (parametro)
{
   self[parametro]();
}
```

El error que arroja es

> TypeError: self[func] is not a function selffunc;

No sé si eso es posible. 
Saludos!

Comment: 1) lo probaste? qué pasó al probar? Es algo fácil de probar! 2) El paránetro es una cadena (string) con la invocación a otra función? Es decir, técnicamente tú le puedes enviar cualquier string (el tuyo está mal formado) pero me preocupa que hagas algo inseguro con ese parámetro.

Comment: Actualmente ya lo hago, pero cuando le mando parámetros no funciona. ¿A que te refieres con algo inseguro?

Comment: Cómo no funciona? QUé error sale en la consola?

Comment: `TypeError: self[func] is not a function
self[func]();`

Comment: cuando invocas self[parametro](); no estas pasando parametros

Comment: veo tu ejemplo y no entiendo lo que quieres hacer, ese parámetro string que pasas por qué es una definición de una función? podrías dar un poco de contexto para entender mejor qué quieres hacer?

Comment: Es que tengo una jAlert que tiene los siguientes botones SI y NO: ovbiamente esa función es global, pero hasta el momento solo lo he ejecutado en funciones que no usan parámetros, sin embargo ahora si la persona selecciona un SI, necesito ejecutar una función pero llevarme un parámetro.

Comment: Exactamente **Victor Perdomo**, y eso es los que necesito saber como hacer.

Comment: pero en javascript no estas obligado a mandar exactamente la misma cantidad de parametros que estan definidos, si tienes una funcion que recibe 0 parametros aun puedes mandarles los parametros que se te ocurran y luego acceder a ellos con `args`

Comment: Esta en tus posibilidades poner un ejemplo?

Comment: @AbrahamRosales ahí puse un ejemplo

Comment: @LPZadkiel Muy amable veré si lo puedo adecuar a mi proposito

Comment: el `self`que mencionas abajo no existe hasta que no lo declares como `self = this`ademas de que debes enviar el contexto con el cual quieres trabajar, si no vas a tener muchos problemas con las referencias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Invocar una función en javascript donde pueda enviar como parámetro
>   otra función y que se pueda ejecutar.

Es posible de varias formas, una de ellas es guardando la función en una variable.

```js
var fun1 = Function("a", "b", "return a * b");
var fun2 = (a,b)=>a*b;
var fun4 = function(a,b){return a*b;};

function ejecuta (parametro)
{
   console.log(parametro(2,4))//<-- ejecutamos
}

ejecuta(fun1)

ejecuta(fun2)

ejecuta(fun4)

ejecuta(Function("a", "b", "return a * b"))
```

Usando específicamente `self`

```js
var otra_funcion = function(){console.log([...arguments].reduce((a,c)=>a+c))}

var nombre = "otra_funcion";

self[nombre](2,4);

self[nombre](2,4,10);

self[nombre](2,4,10,2);

self[nombre]("hola");

self[nombre]("hola ", "que ", "tal");
```

Comment: Tienes razón en esto pero lo que necesito es que se ejecute con `self[otra_funcion]();`

Comment: @AbrahamRosales no tengo una computadora para probarlo ahora, pero estoy casi 100% seguro que se puede,  en ese caso la función es una propiedad de self. Como tú quieres ejecutarla con () al final tendrías que pasar la definición, algo como self.otra_funcion = Function (//codigo)

Comment: De echo lo que si fucnciona como tu indicas, el problema es que la funcion debe ejecutarce en base a la respuesta que selecciona el usuario, si lo hago como tu dices, muestro la pregunta y a la vez ejecuta. Por dicha razón es que uso `self`

Comment: @AbrahamRosales Ahí puse un ejemplo con self que creo que se acerca a lo que quieres.

Answer (score 3):

Según el comentario de quien pregunta

> Es que tengo una jAlert que tiene los siguientes botones SI y NO:
>   ovbiamente esa función es global, pero hasta el momento solo lo he
>   ejecutado en funciones que no usan parámetros, sin embargo ahora si la
>   persona selecciona un SI, necesito ejecutar una función pero llevarme
>   un parámetro.

aconsejo usar lo siguiente:

```js
function jAlert() {
  si('hola', 'mundo', '¿como', 'estás?');
}

function si() {
  // en javascript existe una variable llamada arguments que contiene todos los parámetros de una funcion
  // como ves esta funcion esta declarada sin parámetros pero aún así puedo enviarle parametros, 
  // según buenas prácticas deberías tener varias funciones según la cantidad de parámetros
  // pero si no quieres hacer mas funciones para la respuesta si del usuario, siempre puedes
  // usar la propiedad arguments
  console.log('El usuario respondió si, con el mensaje', ...arguments)
  // considerando que es un arreglo, también la puedes usar de esta forma
  // arguments[0]
  // arguments[1]
}

jAlert();
```

Comment: Muy amable, crees que esto funcione con un `self`

Comment: siempre y cuando las funciones existan si debería funcionar, en tu pregunta pusiste como parámetro algo así como `"function dos(...)"` pero esto no esta bien porque al poner *function* al principio estas definiendo una función lo que deberías poner es solamente `dos(...)` como texto claro

Answer (score 2):

En `javasctipt` existe la función `[eval][1]`, la ventaja que tendrías es que puedes pasar los parámetros (no limitado a 2) como un `array` o una cadena de caracteres y agregarlos a la función.

```js
function testEval(f, a, b)
{
 eval(f+"(" + a + "*" + b +")");
}

testEval("alert", 5, 4);
```

Comment: el problema con eval es que puede ser inseguro si no se sabe lo que se está haciendo

Comment: Me parece interesante, esto funciona con `self` puesto que necesito ejecutarlo en base a la respuesta que el usuario seleccione.

Comment: @LPZadkiel  podrías ampliar más tu comentario en cuanto a la seguridad; ¿Qué afectación da el eval?

Comment: la función `eval` básicamente agarra un texto e intenta convertirlo en código, ahora si el código se genera a partir de texto que ingrese el usuario, este podría ejecutar código javascript que se comunique con tu base de datos y te robe información, o aún peor, que te la borre. Hay que tener un poco de cuidado al usar `eval` simplemente no es recomendado usarla a menos que sepas lo que haces.

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia hay en usar eval o ir directamente a la consola del navegador y ejecutar el código? Para resolver esto se podrá crear una "lista negra" de valores que el usuario no podría ejecutar para evitar una "inyección de código", pero al final, ejecutar javascript del lado del cliente es muy fácil de hacer, con o sin el `eval`.

Comment: @JocksanCruz usar una lista negra es mala idea. Si el usuario ingresa algo malicioso, escapado unicode, ofuscado de alguna forma, encontrará cómo saltar tu lista negra.

Comment: `eval`, además de la inyección de código, tiene que compilar lo que sea que le demos para convertirlo en código. En general es mala idea y por eso creo que el OP está usando una pésima aproximación al problema que desea resolver. [link a SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil#198031)

Comment: Estamos claros que la inyección de código es imposible de detener en javascript, entonces no da ni más ni menos seguridad usar el eval. en cuanto a que tiene que compilar, sí y por esto es que se vuelve la mejor opción en este caso, pues solamente compila la invocación a la función que va a ejecutar con el plus que puede enviar de 0 a n parámetros por lo que el rendimiento no se ve afectado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function dos(parametro_1, parametro_2) {    
    console.log(parametro_1);
    console.log(parametro_2);
}
    
function uno(funcion, parametro_1, parametro_2) {
  funcion(parametro_1, parametro_2);
}

uno(dos, "hello", "world");
```

Comment: Si ya lo habia pensado así, pero en ocaciones puede que necesite ejecutar una funcion que no tenga parámetros, o que necesite ejecutar otra que tenga mas de un parámetro, por lo que esa solución no es factible para este caso.

Comment: @AbrahamRosales Pero si es por no saber cuántos argumentos usas, puedes usar spread syntax! En general, da la impresión que estás usando la aproximación equivocada al problema [link a documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#A_better_apply)

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar un string así, tienes que escapar las comillas simples en el contenido de tus parámetros String cuando van explícitos

```
function uno ('function dos(\'parametro_1\',\'parametro_2\')')
```

Ya resuelto eso, no sé si self permita ejecutar una instrucción como lo estás intentando.

Comment: Podrías ampliar un poco más, respecto a `self`